# Remove second word from string

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Today I was working with a Series comprised of names. I need to erase the second name in every row. My DataFrame looks like this:

```
      Name
John Charles Bloom
Michael Jackson
Peter Rodrigo Aguilera Wayne
```

And my desired output is this:

```
      Name
John Bloom
Michael 
Peter Aguilera Wayne
```

So I tried some things like this:

```
df['Name2']=df.Name.str.replace('\b\w*\b(\b\w*\b)\b\w*\b','')
```

But it didn't work. I'm not an expert in regex, but it shouldn't be that difficult, right?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why not use `df.Name.str.split()` and `.get` the first and last entries instead of a regex? It would be more clear.

Comment: This can be done with the builtin string `split()` method and array indexing, no need for regex

Comment: It looks like you are getting the word boundaries, but not the whitespace, so something like `\b\w*\b\W(\b\w*\b)\W\b\w*\b` should work.

Comment: Why didn't I think about using split, it's way clearer, indeed. Thanks @modesitt and @nathan.medz . I'll also try if `\b\w*\b\W(\b\w*\b)\W\b\w*\b` just to see if I was going by the right approach

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
df.Name.str.replace(r'^(\s*(?:\S+\s+){1})\S+',r'\1')
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to avoid regexes; you can use the `str` accessor. Try this:

```
name_split = df['Name2'].str.split()

(name_split.str[0:1] + name_split.str[2:]).str.join(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string1 = 'John Charles Bloom'
l = string1.split()
(' ').join([l[x] for x in [0].extend(list(range(2,len(l))))])
one = [0]
one.extend(list(range(2,len(l))))
(' ').join([l[x] for x in one])
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will fix your problem:

```
df['Name2'] = df.Name.str.replace('^(\w+)\s+(\w+)(|.+|)', r'\1\g<3>')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your regex is your use of `\b`, which just match a position of word boundaries, but not spaces.

If you insists on regex, you may try something like this

```
^(\s*\w+\s+)\w+\s*(.*)$
```

replace with `\1\2`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/hLlZTS/2/
(I used space instead of `\s` in the demo, just to get around newline matching in regex101.com)

Explanation:

```
^                           start of line
 (         )                group 1: 
  \s*\w+\s+                     some optional spaces, 
                                followed by word characters,
                                followed by spaces
            \w+\s*         some word characters, followed by optional spaces
                           (i.e. the second word and the spaces following it)
                  (.*)     group 2: everything else
                      $    till end of line
```

And you just keep group 1 and group 2 above.

Answer (score 0):

You may split with 1+ whitespaces and then omit the second item if there are at least two items in the resulting list, and then join back the string with spaces:

```
df['Name2']=df['Name'].str.split(r'\s+').apply(lambda x: x[0:1] + x[2:] if len(x) > 2 else x).str.join(' ')
```

Test demo:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['John Charles Bloom','Michael Jackson','Peter Rodrigo Aguilera Wayne', 'Single', 'First Last']})
df['Name2']=df['Name'].str.split(r'\s+').apply(lambda x: x[0:1] + x[2:] if len(x) > 2 else x).str.join(' ')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                           Name                 Name2
0            John Charles Bloom            John Bloom
1               Michael Jackson       Michael Jackson
2  Peter Rodrigo Aguilera Wayne  Peter Aguilera Wayne
3                        Single                Single
4                    First Last            First Last
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to do it is use the `apply()` method:

```
def del_middle(name):    
    name2 = name[0].split(' ')
    name2.pop(1)
    return name2

df.apply(del_middle, axis=1)
```