# Javascript - Remove second capital string onwards

Tags: arrays, string

I'm looking to remove the second word onward of a string.

The string is "QuantityTypeData" I would like it to be "Quantity"

I have looked into this stackoverflow link [JavaScript - Remove all characters after final capital letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54916986/remove-second-word-from-string)

but it seems that it is only removing the last part of a string. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this. There might be other solutions as well. Let me know if any test case fails.

```js
a="QuantityTypeData"
b=a.replace(/[A-Z]/g, match=>` ${match}`)
console.log(b.trim().split(" ")[0])
```

I replaced all uppercase characters by space+character, splitting on space will give all words, first valid word is your answer.

Comment: it works man, thanks for the logic. I haven't thought of that.

Comment: Happy to help mate. Please mark the question solved.